# Map columns from excel to db in rails engine

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, excel, rubygems

I am working on a `rails engine` which takes a excel file as an input and than saves it to `temp` folder in app. Than when i click on validate it validates the file and if there are no errors than it will save file to database. I am able to get the columns of excel file but my problem is that a excel file can have different columns than what in my excel file.

Also i am not generating any migration for engine. `db` table will be provided by the app and my engine will only parse data, validate and than if excel file is valid than it will save all the data in table.

I am getting confused how to set mapping such that it will save data to db.

For e.g. - My engine have model `upload.rb` where i am doing all validation for excel file and than saving it. Now suppose my app have a model `employee.rb` which have columns `first name`, `last name`, `employee id` etc. while my excel file can have any alias or different column name for data. e.g. `fname`, `lname` etc.

Suppose i have `validation` in my engine model, so my engine have no idea about mapping, it will only validate and save the data in db. So mapping needs to be set in my app.

Can anyone tell me how can i set mapping so that whenever my engine is mounted it will parse excel and save to to app's `db` table as per the mapping set ?

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: If you have static database tables and dynamic columns there's gonna be problems mapping. Either use dynamic database tables or forego database mapping and save the csv as a serialized string in the database.

Comment: database tables are static, i can't change them. I am also getting confused. But mapping needs to be done in app's model where engine is mounted. Any idea. My engine will take the mapping and than save data from excel to  db